# Vue.js Unit Test - How to check if component has a method?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, vuejs2

I have a simple component with one method in it. I would like to check if a method in it exists. I know that I can check, if a component contains a certain class or a string, but can't figure out how to check for a method's name. Couldn't find any simple explanation.

Component to test:

```
<template>
    <div>
      <a id="returnButton" href="#" @click="toMainList" class="d-flex align-items-center back-to-button">
          <font-awesome-icon :icon="['fas', 'arrow-left']" class="fontBasicIcon back-to-button-icon" />
          <div>Back</div>
      </a>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import router from '@/router'

    export default {
        name: 'back-to-button',
        data () {
            return {
            }
        },
        methods:{
            toMainList(){
                $router.push('/mainlist');
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Which testing framework are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you use Jest and mount your component to test via `shallowMount` or `mount`, the wrapper returned gives you access to the Vue instance (including all it's methods)

```
const wrapper = shallowMount(Foo)
let instance = wrapper.vm // <- the Vue instance
let myMethod = instance.myMethod // <- a method callend 'myMethod' on the Vue instance

if(myMethod != undefined) {
  console.log("method 'myMethod' exists")
}
```